# Chromium opens on the wrong monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, chromium

I have a dual monitor setup (TV and my PC monitor).

When I launch an application, it always open on the display on which it was launched. Example: If I launch Firefox from my TV it opens on my TV, and if I launch Firefox from my monitor, it opens in my monitor. All applications behave that way except Chromium.

Chromium only opens where it was last launched. Example: If I close Chromium on my TV and then launch it from my monitor (because I want it to open in my monitor), it will open on my TV. I have then to drag it from the TV to my PC monitor.

Is there a way to make Chromium behave like the other apps and open on the display it was launched on?

Specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 19.04, kernel 5.0.0-13
- CPU: i3-2100
- GPU AMD r7D 260x
- RAM: 2x4GB
- SSD: 128GB
- SSD: 500GB
- HDD: 1TB

Comment: I think if you close it from your monitor, then it will also launch from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and helping but it doesn't solve the issue as i still would have to drag the window  on the other monitor. I just want chromium to behave like firefox in the same situation but i can't find how. Someone having the same problem with nautilus solved it by duplicating the app and adding --new-window to the command. However it doesn't seem to work for chromium but i'm probably doing something wrong as i'm new to linux.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, Chromium was the only application that opened up on the wrong monitor, but I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, with GNOME.

What fixed it for me was switching from "join displays" to "single display" (choosing the monitor I wanted chromium to open up in), and then opening up chromium and shutting it down. Then re-enabling "join displays".

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Bah, tried this on Pop!_OS 21.10 and it didn't work unfortunately. Gnome 40 X11 with fractional scaling enabled. Chromium installed via flatpak

Comment: It worked like a charm, amazing! thank you! (Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: Somehow still an issue... Disabling the monitor you don't want the app opening on, open and close the app, then re-enable the other monitor.